# How can I force python apns-client to avoid using SSL 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, apple-push-notifications, pyopenssl

A vulnerability was recently found in SSL 3, and Apple decided to turn it off for push notifications (APNS).  Here is [the announcement](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10222014a) published on Oct 22, 2014.

For the last few days, my development push server has been crashing with this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/django/current/manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/django/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/django/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/django/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/var/django/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/django/releases/7f093a6773161ea21d18c502eaf1a38c76749314/my_app/management/commands/load_apns_feedback.py", line 35, in handle
    for ios_push_notification_hex_token, unavailability_detected_at in feedback_service.feedback():
  File "/var/django/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apnsclient/apns.py", line 696, in feedback
    self._connection.refresh()
  File "/var/django/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apnsclient/apns.py", line 269, in refresh
    self._ensure_socket_open()
  File "/var/django/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apnsclient/apns.py", line 262, in _ensure_socket_open
    self._connect_and_handshake()
  File "/var/django/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apnsclient/apns.py", line 252, in _connect_and_handshake
    self._connection.do_handshake()
  File "/var/django/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1076, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/var/django/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 871, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/var/django/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 22, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exceptionType(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_READ_BYTES', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')]
```

How can I fix this?  Is there a way to tell apns-client to avoid SSL 3 and use TLS instead?

Answer (score 6):

Someone created a [patch for apns-client](https://bitbucket.org/sardarnl/apns-client/pull-request/11/add-option-to-configure-certificate/diff) to make it default to TLS, which is Apple's recommended solution going forward.  It will certainly be merged soon.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to/can't go with the patch, you can always monkey-patch/hack it like this:

```
import OpenSSL
OpenSSL.SSL.SSLv3_METHOD = OpenSSL.SSL.TLSv1_METHOD # work-around for apns-client's inability to specify ssl version combined w/apple's turning off of v3 due to POODLE attack
from apnsclient import Session, Message, APNs  # this line must follow the OpenSSL hack line!!!!
```